# Why do I get this error about file not being found?

Tags: apache2

I am getting this error:

`File does not exist: /var/www/user/home/user/public_html/cgi-sys`

I have only .html files in the document root. Can anyone tell why I am getting this error?

Comment: What are you doing when you get this error? Is it in your logs? We need more information so we can help you.

Comment: yes got this one line from the logs.

Comment: i have created a website all the paths and documentroot are correct   .document root is  /var/www/user/home/user/public_html and have.html file

Comment: Whatever you add to your domain as URI that does not exist will appear in your logs, this is no problem and happens a lot (bots, spiders, crawlers, hackers), just give it a try and add your name like www.yoursite.com/pankajsharma. You'll get a "File does not exist" message.

Answer (score 1):

It's a script kiddie looking for exploits. You can get some fun at him

Redirect rules for .htaccess

```
redirect /cgi-sys http://get.a.life
redirect /cgi-bin http://get.a.life
redirect /scripts http://get.a.life
redirect /MSADC http://get.a.life
redirect /c http://get.a.life
redirect /d http://get.a.life
redirect /_mem_bin http://get.a.life
redirect /msadc http://get.a.life
redirect /MSOffice http://get.a.life
redirect /_vti_bin http://get.a.life
redirectMatch (.*)\cmd.exe$ http://get.a.life$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would search your source code for `cgi-sys` maybe something is linking to that folder? Otherwise contact your hosting provider and ask them why that log entry is appearing. You can also try to access the `cgi-sys` folder from your browser and see if it generates that error. Maybe it's a bot scanning your site.